# Creating new worksheets to existing workbook using datetime as worksheet name

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I have two functions that run one after another. At the end of each function, I run a third function that writes the results to an Excel with the current date and time as the worksheet name. Currently, my code overwrites the current worksheet with the values from the second function instead of creating a new worksheet. How do I resolve this?

```
now = datetime.now()
dt_string = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S")

def login_pass():
    write_xls(status,dt_string)

def login_fail():
    write_xls(status,dt_string)

def write_xls(status,dt_string):
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(dt_string)
    worksheet.write('A1', 'Test', header)
    worksheet.write('B1', 'Status', header)
    worksheet.write('A2', 'Login')
    worksheet.write('B2', status)
    workbook.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    login_fail()
    login_pass()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `write_xls` function, that is called from each worker function, **is creating a new Excel file each time it's called**.

You need to create one "global" Excel file and pass it to your functions to add sheets to. Something like:

```py
now = datetime.now()
dt_string = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S")

def login_pass(workbook):
    write_xls(workbook, status, dt_string)

def login_fail(workbook):
    write_xls(workbook, status, dt_string)

def write_xls(workbook, status, dt_string):
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(dt_string)
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
    login_fail(workbook)
    login_pass(workbook)
    workbook.close()
```